# How to display the image in a template where the source is a TemplateBinding in design view WPF?

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

I've got the following template `ImageTextRadioButton` for a button-like RadioButton with text and the image in it:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton" x:Key="ImageTextRadioButton">
  <Border  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="8" BorderThickness="2">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="ButtonImage" Grid.Column="0" Source="{TemplateBinding Content}" Stretch="None" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
    </Grid>
  </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

(Note that Content in the TemplateBindings is just a string containing the path+filename of the image file).

This works as expected in run mode, but in design mode it doesn't display the image.  The text block displays the correct text, and if I replace the `Image.Source` with a hard-coded value, the image displays correctly too.  But the image just won't display correctly in design mode with the `TemplateBinding` source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argh, I had the .png files as embedded resources, so the converter needed to report the filename as `"/MyProject;component/images/" + value + ".png"` instead of `"../images/" + value + ".png"`  Once I made that change to the converter, everything worked.